# How to validate removing of 'back' button from a form while usability testing?

Tags: usability, forms, mobile, prototype

I tried to validate the removal of the back button from a mobile and a web screen within forms. I used Useberry for usability testing and wasn't sure how to validate this.

I already have a back button in forms and don't have time to collect data on usage.

Is there a way to quickly decide if I should remove the back button or leave it on the screen?

Comment: Hi, Savio. To clarify - are you removing an extra back button (you say you already have one), or are you removing the only back button? If it's the only - why would you need to prevent the user from going back?

Comment: There is only one back button. But I had observed that in most mobile websites, there isn't a back button present. User either uses the left swipe to go back or presses the back button of the browser.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to your question, but it has some technical implications that you might want to check. I personally would vote for keeping an unobtrusive back button in the form in case for some reason the user has trouble using the back button on their device. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25728/is-a-back-button-needed-on-a-web-form

Answer (score 1):

> “Unfortunately some users don’t trust the browser back button because of their experiences of poorly designed forms that lose data when they click back. The solution is to provide a form-specific back button.”

In the absence of research, I’d retain the back button.

https://adamsilver.io/blog/where-to-put-buttons-on-forms/#put-the-back-button-above-the-form